# How do i add country code dynamically?

Tags: iphone, ios4

I need to add country code to a phone number dynamically when i select a country from the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store both the things in the phone (i.e Country Name and Country code). When user selects a particular country name Then mark its row index and access the country code of same index from its array and add it to the phone number. This is way that you can use.

Comment: u mean that i have to store both code and country name in a file. But  is there any API which can help us to get the Country Code ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get all country name as well as country code in different array like this:

```
NSArray *countryArray = [NSLocale ISOCountryCodes]; // All country code array
NSMutableArray *sortedCountryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSString *countryCode in countryArray) 
{
    NSString *displayNameString = [locale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode value:countryCode];
    [sortedCountryArray addObject:displayNameString];
}
[sortedCountryArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]; //All country array
```